# md-option within md-select Angular Material 2.0.0 beta 10

Tags: angular4-forms

Select All option for selecting all the values in md-option with in md-select. I am populating md-option by using ngFor and i am using formControl. I can see the checkboxes for all the md-option values. But I am not able to check all the checkboxes from typescript(.ts) file. How do put select all option? 
I am trying control.setValue(arrayvalues); But it doesn't check the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote [compareWith] = compareById(obj1, obj2) attribute for md-select in my HTML page and in the .ts file write the below method {`compareById(obj1, obj2){ return obj1 = obj2.code}`
}. It works for me.